# Error while running a shiny app on ubuntu

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-server

I have made a shiny app which works fine on windows, but when I tried running the same on my ubuntu system the app exists abruptly and I get following error

```
Loading required package: TTR
Version 0.4-0 included new data defaults. See ?getSymbols. 
Error in library(rstudio) : there is no package called ‘rstudio’
```

After this I tried installing the 'rstudio' package and I am getting the following message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rstudio’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

My R version is: 3.2.1 and my RStudio version is: 0.99.467

Note: I am new to ubuntu and the only reason I shifted to ubuntu, was to to use shiny-server.

Comment: I have the same problem in Windows. I tried to use `rstudio::viewer`, and get the `there is no package called ‘rstudio’` message. Using RStudio 0.99.467. I'll try a downgrade in Windows.

Comment: @Murta, the `viewer` function is in the `rstudioapi` package. There is no `rstudio` package. Use `rstudioapi::viewer`.

Answer (score 3):

The `rstudio` package comes with the installation of RStudio (Desktop or Server). If you need to use the `rstudio` package, you probably need to install RStudio (Dekstop or Server version).

You can do that from here:
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/

That said, I'm not clear on why you would need to load the `rstudio` package.

Answer (score 1):

That is because there is no package called `rstudio` (at least not on CRAN anyways). Either there is a typo and you really meant the `rstudioapi` package, or on your windows system you actually did install a package named `rstudio` that, however, was distributed from another source other than CRAN. I'd suggest try removing the line `library(rstudio)` and see if it works.